# Incorrect inference when using the return keyword in an identity function, or when using an optional argument

Tags: typescript, types, return, arguments, inference

I'm running into very weird behavior when using identity functions. I'm writing a wizard system with schema (attached is a playground link with a very simplified version), and using constrained identity function to get inference.

The problem occurs in one of the properties that cannot be inferred when I use  either of these:

- When the returned value from the identity function is using the `return` keyword (rather than a single-line return wrapped with parentheses).
  OR
- When declaring an optional argument in the identity function. The argument is declared in the type definition of the identity function, and when using `Parameters<typeof myFunction>` it's inferred correctly both when declaring the argument and when I not.

Both these issues are super weird to me, which means I'm either missing something very fundamental or I have found 2 rare bugs.

This reproduces in all available playground versions (tried down to 3.3.3), and also in 4.8.

[Playground link with relevant code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQEoTgewCcATAHgGdhCBLAOwHMAaKAV1oGtb8B3WgPigB6QVGT5i1AGbUIxKJML5kUItXp1UAG3lEowJFHKp20fJL0GIAD1TIwmiMylRqwKMXwRytAORu0JoYQtOQQAFBhoJCwwBBgAGJscMDU+LSkYVBQACrwSGhQ1rG0xOSwiCjoWHmVjGECWAAUqLQg+nT0AFysHFy8AJSYAgDemVCEEKgetJoghhVo3bkLqGMTU2mzevgAgiHcEITkAPzdjSYg5N0XZjk1aIMYAmycPLRhAL4RkkkpaYaxMCkZb5dBFYKlcqgzBQyp8RpjLKUOIANS03RggMStGSqXSILhdSy-QxWN+eOB91QI0R4wgwBYhFoANRWjGXzCwigAFEABo7ACyAAUADLcmBQABC3JFAHkAOqdTkiABy+BScGg+mgEwZTNkKgARgArPBuW5abQ-HF-EIuMrawy2CAAQhyBgkkkkh2CmrKqAmLloSq5AFooNwkNrCBHoCxQhZoAADXWM2hJqAXbhEOS6LhuRrHF1F-rKqDh+VRpAxg5QBCoABuWoMAfoLGQwTckl0jqTyLAGetuP+efVADooPmLKg3M4AJLufBQJNCgPO2JHUhRCC3ZAgTGszQsCB8DMQJvMyPBRNQVvtzv20TUcjkDpOYA+Mp0b2ECZyAi-maWyNC6pZlvKsrYAA0jA3RJhc5AZs+QY-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-1QFprRA-QIMxd1MUmXsEPmdD1lw7S9mI85rl65cGNYwauOTcbda+sTpPk5T1PLrTDD0-XcVM9LAKpfQ6WZZzkDc9Z+W0IVAvl6Vwvt1AYvK1LSUH0LIuFwrbUSyrtJ14ZPVhEAA)

Probably better to check the playground for code examples, but there:

TYPES DECLERATIONS:

```js
type Schema = Record<string, unknown> // modified from original for the sake of the example, if it doesn't make sense

type StepFunction<
  TSchema extends Schema = Schema,
> = (anything: unknown) => {
  readonly schema: TSchema
  readonly toAnswers?: (keys: keyof TSchema) => unknown
}

function step<TSchema extends Schema = Schema>(
    stepVal: StepFunction<TSchema>,
  ): StepFunction<TSchema> {
    return stepVal
  }
```

EXAMPLES:
Notice the returned object of all functions is the same! The differences are in:

- whether we use the `return` keyword or not (?!?!)
- Whether we have the argument for the `step` function or not. not that if I do `Parameters<typeof myStepValue>` even when the argument is missing, it's inferred correctly (!)

```js
// WORKS: `keys` is inferred based on the `schema`
// - no argument for `step` function
// - no `return` keyword
const workingExample = step(() => ({
  schema: {
    attribute: 'anything',
  },
  toAnswers: keys => {
    // RESULT: `keys` inferred successfully as `attribute`
    type Test = string extends typeof keys ? never : 'true'
    const test: Test = 'true'
    return { test }
  },
}))
```

```js
// FAILS: `keys` is not inferred based on the `schema`
// - has argument for `step` function
const nonWorkingA = step(_something => ({
  schema: {
    attribute: 'anything',
  },
  toAnswers: keys => {
    // RESULT: `keys` failed to inferred hence defaults to `string`
    type Test = string extends typeof keys ? never : 'true'
    const test: Test = 'true'
    return { test }
  },
}))
```

```js
// FAILS: `keys` is not inferred based on the `schema`
// - has `return` keyword rather than a "single-return" return with parentheses
const nonWorkingB = step(() => {
  return {
    schema: {
      attribute: 'anything',
    },
    toAnswers: keys => {
      // RESULT: `keys` failed to inferred hence defaults to `string`
      type Test = string extends typeof keys ? never : 'true'
      const test: Test = 'true'
      return { test }
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a TypeScript inference issue about context-sensitive expressions (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49951 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599).

However, I did find a temp solution - by wrapping the return value with an identity function, the edge cases work.

e.g.:

```js
step(_something => (identityOfStep({
  schema: {
    attribute: 'anything',
  },
  toAnswers: keys => {
    // RESULT: `keys` failed to inferred hence defaults to `string`
    type Test = string extends typeof keys ? never : 'true'
    const test: Test = 'true'
    return { test }
  },
})))
```

[Example in a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQEoTgewCcATAHgGdhCBLAOwHMAaKAV1oGtb8B3WgPigB6QVGT5i1AGbUIxKJML5kUItXp1UAG3lEowJFHKp20fJL0GIAD1TIwmiMylRqwKMXwRytAORu0JoYQtOQQAFBhoJCwwBBgpAAq8EhoUNaxtMTksIgoqAIYAN5hUFCEEKgetJoghrloAFxQSfWoJWUVVTV6+ACCIdwQhOQA-E0AFCYg5E1TZs3JeQCUmAJsnDy0YQC+EVHQMLFgAGJscMDU+LSk7S0p6OnBWTn3mC95jGEFUOOotCD6Oj0JrrLi8FYYASHOKJRZoPgRSRnC5XQxHWGtNJWDLPOHoLB4vjjdqlShxU60c6XWgANS0TWhJ2R1Ix9z4n1KSwZRwpVKurLyAmKpVK5WALEItDR5OZVzpmnauzCSMpKKlZLAAEliMELqBeWqBalHplsni3oTiSLpWB5dyYXdBRyoFyYg7CVBhSKxRL1Ud5YqImFhFAAKIADV6AFkAAoAGVDMCgACFQ3GAPIAdQawZEADl8Bc4NB9NAfZLZCoAEYAKzwbnmWm0Kr5IRc2VLhlsEAAhM0DBJJJIhsFi9lUOUXLQcyGALRQbhIUuEBfQFihCzQAAG5doW6gU24RDkui4bnGIx7l6Wuag88XEGXq6gCFQADcSwYJ-QWMhdToV07LcNX3Fs1RUFczwAOigAtYgsVA3GcTV3HwKAtxjCdu1iYZSH2eZkBARl5RYCA+H3CAPylB8pU7b9f3-ahsmQJjyCBJxgB8bI6GHQhyjkAg+Prbpxh7G9b0zdNsAAaRgJotymch9yYqdeP4qAq1QUIT1ogxgNaLdb3nLgoHov9aDcSRdGAo5QNlLY5ygEyd0fX190PY8wgIEI3CPQh2CBUMbDsBw3g1cZxghARxi9chWiaL1SkQqhqCrFhYiaHw-gBBAgR8Z1tmdYA+gGIYZgPCBplWT0SSEERsETABVOMEnkxT93IFg4GLWRuNoXjR2gLT0OSmg0tiQzrX2ZovDcLBKBoBgsRxDtwAgeZFKgEYnMooYoEyqhSJ8WrvMoPRZqaBJZrePxCCO2rd09c6zt2UpCp2JZxJDY5ek1OM5PQ9r2ycwtVKGdTNO0lRdO3OL7kMxzX3HQgf3MyzrJA+R7K8q4zq4WhMyIAKGF6MKjnGAB9cglEfXKlshH5YvimrrVG1L0ogTLssBBh8sVIqSvIQZhlmSrsgZxK6pwJqWrasXQNQahND6gbKWgJA1fcCBJFQFhNGADs0Jsxb6EmkVpqus75pSpaTWefDzE27baF2lcDruiBjutU63FiShLuurBbvu61HsKZ63FeqB3u2T6Im+37-rl6ZlOyM8waEuRIcrVEgLhvIEZEeckfQ3d3Mqvy5EIRCkEA18pXQAAiNiGAcWdd0bjpxUlBdXAQKAwAnXUkFCcgcZ8kGCaJoFkzJuIIqilmu99JfSWZyWkuAFLxs5qAsv+Hn6D5613qmwXhfKzaJdq0oQwamBmtawH5fkRXlYzwaX0-nUdb1g2enQgtIEZspprRmlbNEJtlpPFWpADaYsto7Q-G7Peh1PY3ygD7COAcIHB3QdaUUrke7hz9pHWqp9o4fXjiISSMlNR5gAOJQEzJqBIAAJKAmoAAioY8wJFYQATSgMcRqeYADC-D0x5hgOPM6flib0EzH3bUupXAgANNSUm1t55Uxpofaq4wNQqIsmojRVwYrtHzo0Vepkt5jQ5lzA+dMj4FQFv0IWZVRZVWvqA6Ils5qQKBNA00eg1rwKqs7V2+1UEey9iKLBpCcEBLwXEwh3cpQkOulHGOn1xJYPkUCJR+hjF6nUfZWe2iwAL2ql6R6RidQmP1PZCx1orGoAShgtmO9HE5Tys6N6-SejuIvl48WQoMEW0DoE222IYGhLgY7BBkTkHRJSRghJF1wHJLQak70RCMkR0oSfAqN5Y5AA)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your type:

```js
type Step<TSchema> = (store: TSchema) => {
  data: {
    schema: TSchema
    toAnswers?: (keys: keyof TSchema) => unknown
  }
}

function step<TSchema extends Schema>(x: Step<TSchema>) {
  return x
}
```

In my opinion, there is two reasons:

- in `nonWorkingA` there is two sources of truth - one from parameter and one from internal object structure (parameter `_store` implicitly has `any` type), and if you specify type of `_store` it's should work
- in `nonWorkingB` you using `statements` (return) instead of `expressions` and typescript can not inference types

I've been working on this for almost 3 hours but still couldn't figure out how to make a normal type inference

Comment: Thanks for investing time on this!

- For the 2 sources of truth reason, I'm not sure this is the case, because if I replace the `toAnswers` functions with just `toAnswers: key keyof TSchema` - it's inferred correctly. It doesn't work just because it's an argument in a function.

- For the `statments` vs `expressions` - is this documented anywhere? Couldn't find any reference for this difference. Syntax wise it's weird to me because using `({})` instead of `return` is syntactic sugar AFAIK.

Comment: @ShayDavidson no, it's not syntactic sugar. `() => ({})` - is expression (it's same as `() => 5`), but `() => { return {} }` don't, because we using block and return statement here.